# Why is the following lex/yacc generating segmentation fault?

Tags: bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I want to sum the numbers on a single line.

e.g.

```
1 2 3 '\n'   =>  prints 6
1 '\n'       =>  prints 1
0 '\n'       =>  prints 0
'\n'         =>  prints 0
```

For this purpose, I have figured that following regular expression would suffice :

```
 ((NUMBER)* "\n")+
```

I make use of lex/yacc combo for it. I understand that lex would suffice but this is just a small throwaway program specifically to know how yacc works.

I made the following grammar for the above regular expression :

```
lines -> lines line
lines -> line

line -> numbers '\n'

numbers -> numbers NUMBER
numbers -> (empty)
```

But putting the input as `1 (enter)` generates segmentation fault. I cannot understand why it is happening.

---

The yacc program (in.y) is:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

extern int yylex();
int yyerror(const char *s);

%}

%union
{
    int num;
    char ch;
}

%token <num> NUMBER
%type  <num> numbers


%start lines

%%

lines   :   line lines      ;
        |   line            ;
        ;

line    :   numbers '\n'    { printf("%s\n", $1); }

numbers :   NUMBER numbers  { $$ = $1 + $2; }
        |   NUMBER          { $$ = $1; }
        ;

%%

int main()
{
    return( yyparse() );
}

int yyerror(const char * s)
{
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", s );
}
```

---

And the lex program is (in.l):

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"

//extern YYSTYPE yylval;
%}

%%

[0-9]+      { yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n          { return yylval.ch = yytext[0]; }
.           { ; }

%%

int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
}
```

To be exhaustive, I am running it under Cygwin emulating using flex/bison as:

`yacc -d in.y; flex in.l; gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile your code with gcc flag `-s` and then run your program (`a.out`) using valgrind (a memory error detector), you would discover that the problem is on the `printf`.

So when you have a `%s` argument on the `printf`, it will be waiting for a pointer to a null-terminated string. However, you are passing an integer. When `printf` is accessing it will start at the address on `$1` and the continue till a `\0` (null char) appear in the memory.

You just want to print a simple integer. Replace the `%s` with `%d` and it will work.

The entire rule looks like that:

```
line    :   numbers '\n'    { printf("%d\n", $1); }
```

Comment: Oh my God. Is this what I wasted four hours of my life on?! :D Thanks anyway for the debugging tools info and pointing out my silly, silly mistake!